# What settings should be changed in my.ini configuration to change the folder where the databases are stored?

Tags: mysql

I heard that it is necessary to change "datadir".

I set "datadir" to another folder. I copied my bases to it. I set "datadir" back, deleted the databases from the old place via PhpMyAdmin (Because now my databases are in the new place. In the old place I do not need it.). Again set "datadir" in a new place. I go to PhpMyAdmin - there are bases. I open some database, try to open a table, and I get an error that the table does not exist. If I start a site that uses this database, then there will be exceptions that the tables do not exist.

If I do not delete the database from the old place, then everything works fine.

As I understand it, changing the "datadir" is not enough. I need to change some other setting. But which one?

Comment: This might be better suited to dba